# Flutter iOS on Circle CI

Tags: ios, flutter, cocoapods, circleci

Currently I'm trying to build flutter project on circle CI. When trying to install pods I got following output.

```
-> Fetching podspec for `Flutter` from `Flutter`
[!] No podspec found for `Flutter` in `Flutter
```

My config

```
  build_ios:
    resource_class: large
    working_directory: ~/project/ios
    macos:
      xcode: 12.3.0 
    steps:
      - checkout:
          path: ~/project
    
      - run:
          name: download flutter SDK
          command: if ! test -f "~/flutter_sdk.zip"; then curl -o ~/flutter_sdk.zip https://storage.googleapis.com/flutter_infra/releases/stable/macos/flutter_macos_1.22.5-stable.zip; fi
      - run:
          name: unzip flutter SDK
          command: unzip ~/flutter_sdk.zip -d ~
      - run:
          name: export flutter path
          command: echo 'export PATH="$PATH:~/flutter/bin"'  >> $BASH_ENV

      - run: flutter doctor
      - run: flutter pub get
      - run:
          name: Bundle install
          working_directory: ./ios
          command: bundle install
      - run:
          name: Pod install
          working_directory: ./ios
          command: bundle exec pod install --repo-update
```

Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

In case someone will have same issue: I was missing the following command

```
  - run: flutter precache --no-android
```